# Need help to fix this login code

Tags: php, session

I'm newbie to PHP, currently i'm doing first project to build a website which use to evaluate employee. The requirements are using PDO to prevent SQL injection and session.
The login.php work, but when it switch to cpanel page ( which include session.php ) it doesn't show anything. Seem like i messed up the code with PDO and mysql command too. 
I use php -f session.php in terminal and have this line :

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: login_user in /var/www/docs/cent285
/project1/source/session.php on line 7
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object 
in /var/www/docs/cent285/project1/source/session.php on line 10
```

Loginform.php

```
 <form action="source/login.php" method="post">
 <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
 <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" type="password">
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
 </form>
```

login.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) 
   {
  $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
   }
else
    {
                $pdo = connect();
                $username   = $_POST['username'];
                $password   = $_POST['password'];
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "select id, division, department from " .
                  "check_user(:usr,:pass) as (id integer, " .
                  "division text, department text)";
                $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $myarray = array();
                $myarray[':usr'] = $username;
                $myarray[':pass'] = $password;
                $statement->execute($myarray);
                $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if ($row['id'] > 0) {

                  session_start();
                  $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
                  $div = $row['division'];
                  $dept = $row['department']; 
                  $loggedIn = TRUE; 
                   header("Location: ../cpanel.php");
                  exit(); }
                else
                    {
                        mysql_close($pdo);
                        header("location:../404.html");
                    }
      }
   }
?>
```

session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
 $connection= "pgsql:host=localhost dbname=proj1_db " .
        "user=bob password=somepass";

$user_check= $_SESSION['login_user'];
$ses_sql="select username from users where username='$user_check'";
$row = $ses_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection); 
header('Location: ../index.html');
}
?>
```

cpanel.php

```
<?php
include('source/session.php');
  $pdo = connect();
  if (!$pdo) { 
  die("Could not connect"); 
  } 
  $div = $_GET["div"];
  $dept = $_GET["dept"];
  var_dump($div);
  var_dump($dept);
  $myarray = array();
  if ($div !== $dept) {
  $sql = "select * from users_evaluations_view " .
  "where department=:dept";
  $myarray[':dept'] = $dept;
  }
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute($myarray);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Home Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="profile">
<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
<?php 
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['uid'] . "<br />\n"; }
?>
<b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

config.php

```
<?php
function connect(){
    $pdoString= "pgsql:host=localhost dbname=proj1_db " .
    "user=bob password=somepass";
    $pdo = new PDO($pdoString);
    return $pdo;
   }
?>
```

Comment: why are you doing `mysql_close($pdo);`/`mysql_close($connection);`? you can't close a `PDO` connection with a `mysql` function.

Comment: In **session.php** page your `$connection` is just a string, you're not actually connected to a database. You're doing `$ses_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` without executing the query. And you're mixing APIs.